# crond: sendmail error while running a python script in crontab

Tags: centos, cron, python, aws

I have a script which runs perfectly in terminal, but when I tried to run that in crontab every "5 minutes", I got following errors in /var/log/messages:

```
crond: sendmail: fatal: parameter inet_interface: no local interface found for ::1
```

Crontab entry:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/python /scripts/python/account.py >> /script/python/account.log
```

**Note**: In my script I am running an aws command (Which might be the reason):

```
aws cloudwatch put-metric-data <----options and parameters---->
```

If anyone could shed some light as to why I am getting this error and to what I can do to overcome this, that would be a great help.

Thanks.

**update 1**

Only command that is trying to send information out of system is the aws one, I am using following code to run that command:

```
os.system("aws cloudwatch put-metric-data <----options and parameters---->")
```

Comment: Posting the full script would be helpfull

Comment: @RamanSailopal, I can't post the whole script due to security reasons, Although if you could tell me what this error is related to, I can provide you with the needed code snippet..

Comment: What flavor of `sendmail` is this?

Comment: @thrig, I am not getting any other information apart from this. I am not using sendmail or any such command which require network usage (apart from aws command).

Comment: Find the sendmail binary. Find what package it belongs to.

Comment: cron is trying to send email, but the email subsystem isn’t configured correctly. The python script is irrelevant.

Comment: @thrig, I am sure that my script is not calling any sendmail binary. Although I can't comment on the AWS command side. Is it possible I can make some updates in system to overcome this error?

Comment: @JeffSchaller There is no email system configured on the system. As you mentioned, if python script is irrelevant, is it possible to pin point the problematic line?

Comment: It's my opinion that you could reproduce this problem simply by trying to send email to yourself at the command-line (no cron, no python script).

Comment: @JeffSchaller: But the OP has said that the script works perfectly when run at the command line. (Do you have something in mind that I’m overlooking?)

Comment: @Amit: If you make a modified copy of your script and remove the ``aws`` line and run that via cron, what happens?

Comment: Maybe it runs successfully but produces some stderr , which isn’t being redirected.

Comment: Then where is `sendmail` coming from in the log? `strace` things.

Comment: You should rework the script until you can reproduce this error with a script that you can post - find the minimal example script that produces the same error.

Comment: @G-Man, Sorry for the late reply, I did what you said, commented the AWS command, but now also nothing is running.

Comment: @JeffSchaller, As you can see in the update 2, I am not getting any error at all in /var/log/messages, but still that script is not running, in crontab. If I run the command added in crontab as it is in the terminal, it runs successfully. Not sure why it's happening, going through the script again, but that's a problem of a different domain, thanks anyway.

Comment: @thrig, I am not sure where it was coming from, this was the first time I saw such error, Check Update 2, I made the changes, but still not sure why those changes are required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's what resolved my problem**

I updated `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file as:

1. comment out: `inet_interfaces: all`
2. add `inet_protocol: ipv4`

Now I am not getting any sendmail error at all in `/var/log/messages`.